# Industry of a company in Schema.org

Tags: ontology, network-structure, industry, semantic-web

I would like to specify industry of companies (e.g., Financial, Tech, Telecom, etc.). In Schema.org, [industry](https://schema.org/industry) is only specified on Job posting. Could you let me know what schema.org type to use as the industry of a company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using https://schema.org/naics on Organization since industry on job posting refers to NAICS codes based on their example. See screenshot below.

[image: Industry example]

You can find NAICS codes [here](https://www.census.gov/naics/).